# C enum: unknown type name

Tags: c, enums

I have this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    enum Days { asd=0,Lun,Mar,Mer,Gio,Ven,Sab,Dom };
    Days TheDay;
    time_t ltime;
    struct tm *Tm;

    ltime=time(NULL);
    Tm=localtime(&ltime);
    int j = Tm->tm_wday;
    TheDay = Days(j);

    printf("[%d] %d/%d/%d, %d:%d:%d\n",
            TheDay, /* Mon - Sun */
            Tm->tm_mday,
            Tm->tm_mon,
            Tm->tm_year+1900,
            Tm->tm_hour,
            Tm->tm_min,
            Tm->tm_sec);
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error:

> try.c:6:5: error: unknown type name ‘Days’

Comment: use as it is when dealing with the enum value as int. doesn't make sense `int j = Tm->tm_wday; TheDay = Days(j);` only `Tm->tm_wday`. or make function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not C:

```
enum Days { asd=0,Lun,Mar,Mer,Gio,Ven,Sab,Dom };
Days TheDay;
```

The name of the new type is `enum Days` and not `Days` (which is the enum tag).

You have to use:

```
enum Days { asd=0,Lun,Mar,Mer,Gio,Ven,Sab,Dom };
enum Days TheDay;
```

or use a typedef:

```
typedef enum Days Days;
```

to be able to use `Days` as a type name.

Comment: Also `typedef enum { ... } Days;`.

Comment: Additionally, the asker is likely accustomed to C++, where `enum Days` declares Days as a type name as well as an enumeration.